# IR out not doing anything - irsend

Tags: gpio, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, lirc

Bought my first pi (pi 3 - Model B )last week and an IR reciever, thought as a first project I would have it send IR codes to my tv using `irsend` (plan is to then create nodejs app and have it integrate with alexa). Anyway I have set everything up the way I believe is correct but when using the command `irsend SEND_ONCE MY_REMOTE_CONTROL KEY_POWER` for example nothing happens. I have gone through the whole process of recording the remote, creating the relevant config files etc.

When running `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` I can see output in my terminal like

```
space 16300
pulse 95
space 28794
pulse 80 
space 19395
```

`irsend LIST MY_REMOTE_CONTROL ""` even returns following for example

```
irsend: 000000000000c837 KEY_POWER
```

I was just wondering if anyone has had this problem in the past and how they went about fixing it

This is my config is setup

**/boot/config.txt**

```
# Added this
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18
```

**/etc/modules**

```
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=18 gpio_out_pin=17
```

**/etc/lirc/hardware.conf**

```
LIRCD_ARGS="–uinput –listen"
DRIVER="default"
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"
```

I have also run the following to make sure everything is up to date

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rpi-update
```

If anyone has any suggestions or troubleshooting ideas then please advise, any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: Do u have an IR Emitter? Or just the receiver?

Comment: I have this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00T9JPA4O/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1, which from the description says it can control any IR device such as TV's etc

Comment: There seem to be two blocks of jumper pads on the board.  Are they relevant.

Comment: you will have to excuse my lack of knowledge regarding the setup of the IR board, could you explain what possible issue this could cause ? thanks

Comment: I have no idea.  The documentation should mention what they are for (if indeed they are jumpers).